# Create a HTTPS Tunnel to avoid network hard limitations

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, https, tunnel

Here is my problem :
At work, if I don't want to use my phone for everything I use the provided connection to the internet, that goes through a network that has strict restrictions : basically all protocols besides HTTPS are blocked. It's been a hassle and has prevented me to work efficiently several times, but despite my complaints to the administration the rules are nowhere near changing.

So what I am thinking I could do :
Create a HTTPS Tunnel to a personal computer at my place (Raspberry pi I just acquired) to be able to do anything I can do from my place.
The computer I use between my work and my home runs on macOS.

1. Are there people here that would know if channeling all my connections through such a tunnel could be done (like using a proxy) ?
2. Do you have a better idea ? (Yes I thought about using a VPN but that protocol is blocked too)

1.st Challenge : I don't know thing one about Tunnels

2.nd Challenge : Connecting the Raspberry Pi at my place to be securely accessible from outside my home network.

Thank you already for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but a product like https://ngrok.com in theory allows you to access a SSH port over https by forwarding TCP traffic.

If that works then you can set-up a SOCKS proxy or something using good old SSH or any other tunnel.

Ngrok encapsulates your TCP traffic within HTTPS so whatever firewall or filter is none the wiser.

Comment: I am having a look at ngrok, although I am not sure yet how it works, when I look at its available commands, I see one regarding HTTP Tunnel, but not HTTPS

Comment: In the lower half of the documentation it refers to  HTTPS and TCP.